# How do I test a nested Ruby on Rails controller with RSpec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have a **Rails** controller named `PagesController` that is nested as follows in *app/controllers/sevenpages/public/pages_controller.rb*:

```
module Sevenpages
  module Public
    class PagesController < ApplicationController
      layout nil
      def show 
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I want to test this controller using **RSpec**

When I create the following test in *spec/controllers/sevenpages/pubic/pages_controller_spec.rb*:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Sevenpages:Public::PagesController do
  describe 'GET #show' do
    get :show, use_route: :sevenpages
    {{ tests go here }}
  end
end
```

I get the following error:

```
undefined method `get' for #<Class:0x007fe5c88e4300> (NoMethodError)
```

Now I understand what this error message means. The problem is that the `RSpec::Rails::ControllerExampleGroup` methods aren't being automatically included in the controller test, so the standard Rails methods such as `get`, `post`, etc. aren't available in the test.

I've tried all the recommended solutions that I can find without luck. Here's what I've tried:

- Ensure that `spec/spec_helper.rb` contains `require 'rspec/rails'`
- Explicitly declare the test type using:

  `describe Sevenpages::Public::PagesController, type: :controller do`
- Explicitly include the controller example group using:

  `include RSpec::Rails::ControllerExampleGroup` in the controller body

I'm at a loss as to what else I can try. I should note that I'm using:

- Rails 3.2.11
- RSpec 2.12.2

**My app is a Rails engine**, thus the `use_route` parameter to the `get` method.

The only thing I can think of is that RSpec doesn't know how to handle a controller that's nested this deeply. Is there some syntax that I should be aware of to enable RSpec to properly parse this as a controller test?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you posted above has the test in a describe block. Typically with Rspec you put the test in a "it" block. Like:

```
describe Sevenpages:Public::PagesController do
  describe 'GET #show' do
    it 'should work' do
      get :show, use_route: :sevenpages
      {{ tests go here }}
    end
  end
end
```

If you try this does the method become properly defined?

Comment: Doh! Thanks Pete. I got bunny-trailed off the obvious due to the increased complexity introduced by my nesting. Well, hopefully the question will serve as a summary of possible solutions to someone having the actual problem of their controller not being recognized as such by RSpec. :D